# no function clause matching in Access.get/3 map Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have the following data:

```elixir
data = %{
  "items" => [
    %{
      "countryCode" => "AF",
      "id" => 32_000_007,
      "isCountry" => true,
      "name" => "Afghanistan"
    },
    %{
      "countryCode" => "AX",
      "id" => 32_000_008,
      "isCountry" => true,
      "name" => "Åland Islands"
    },
    %{
      "countryCode" => "AL",
      "id" => 32_000_009,
      "isCountry" => true,
      "name" => "Albania"
    }
  ],
  "paging" => %{"cursors" => %{}}
}
```

When I call this code:

```elixir
location_id = 32_000_007
Enum.find(data, fn location -> location["id"] == location_id end)
```

I get the following error:

> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Access.get/3
>
> ```elixir
> The following arguments were given to Access.get/3:
>
>     # 1
>     {"items", [...]}
>
>     # 2
>     "id"
>
>     # 3
>     nil
> ```

Why do I get this error and how can I extract the item given the id?

Comment: Also, the question is difficult to handle since a good deal of information is both big and outside of StackOverflow. It would be better to rephrase the question with a simpler test case.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `get` is not a list but a tuple. As you can see at the end of the full error message, there is not `get` function for this value.
Reading the entire message, it seems you need to do more to analyse it. If the result of the API call is in variable `r`, something like `elem(r, 1) |> Enum.at(0) |> Access.get("location") |> Access.get("id")`

Comment: why `elem(r, 1)`? and how will that look like here? like `rem(data, 1)`?

Comment: I also tried it like this https://sourceb.in/mHZeWkKvza but now its saying `nil`

Comment: elem(r, 1) is to keep only the second element of the response, the list. Also, your second text in https://sourceb.in/mHZeWkKvza is almost useless since we don't see the data structure. See my comment to your question.

Comment: uh yea, I tried to play around with it but I cant find a working way on how to access that deep list

Comment: As I said, the question is not clear, it focuses on the API (which seems irrelevant) and not on the data structure (which seems to be the real problem). IMHO, you should rewrite your question. Here is a possible way to rephrase it, with a possible solution (if I understood correctly) : https://write.as/bortzmeyer/asking-a-question-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Access.get/3
>
> ```elixir
> The following arguments were given to Access.get/3:
>
>     # 1
>     {"items", [...]}
>
>     # 2
>     "id"
>
>     # 3
>     nil
> ```

Is generated because you're doing the equivalent of this:

```elixir
{"items", []}["id"]
```

This is because the `["id"]` operator is syntax sugar for the [Access behaviour](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html). It is telling you that it's not possible to access a key called `id` on a `{"items", []}` tuple.

The reason you have an `{"items", []}` tuple is that it's the first key-value pair of `data`, which is what you get by doing `Enum.find(data, ...)`. What you actually want is the *value* of the `items` key, so you should do: `Enum.find(data["items"], ...)`:

```elixir
iex> Enum.find(data["items"], fn location -> location["id"] == location_id end)
%{
  "countryCode" => "AF",
  "id" => 32000007,
  "isCountry" => true,
  "name" => "Afghanistan"
}
```

Comment: ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for nil of type Atom. This protocol is implemented

Comment: `get_in(data, ["items", Access.filter(&match?(%{"id" => 32_000_008}, &1))])` :)

Comment: I was hoping the OP might learn something from this answer, but judging by just replying with an unrelated error message, I guess not 

Comment: Warning, your edition of the question changed it a bit (the top-level structure was a tuple, not a map as in the original question).

Comment: @bortzmeyer that's true, however the OP's code was operating on the `data` variable extracted from the tuple - I simplified it down to the core question. Anyway if the OP isn't willing to think for themselves beyond copy/pasting code and quoting the output, I'm not going to reply further.